# How to get the next identity number used in SQL Server 2005 and ASP?

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, ado, identity, autonumber

I was previously getting the next available autonumber used in Access by doing a simple query like so:

```
SELECT RecordNumber, Info 
FROM myTABLE 
WHERE 0 = 1
```

This way I could create a variable to hold the currentRecord and it will use the same autonumber that Access was going to use when I was updating the row

Example

```
rs.AddNew
currentRecord = rs("RecordNumber")

rsInfo = "SomeFormData" & currentRecord
rs.Update
rs.Close
```

Now this use to work on MS Access, but in SQL Server 2005, I am not getting back the Identity created by the new record. "SomeFormData" is been inserted correctly, the RecordNumber field in SQL is been populated by the new auto number but I don't have the RecordNumber in my variables and I need it to continue filling related forms, that save data to related tables and need to save the currentRecord number.

**Question**: is there a way to get this unique number back when doing a new insert?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`IDENT_CURRENT('tableName')` (include the single quotes) returns the current value of the identity for the given table.  This value should be the last-assigned identity value used in the table.  In other words, you will have a row with this identity value already in the table, unless that row has been deleted.  The identity value that will be assigned on the next `INSERT` will be `IDENT_CURRENT('tableName') + IDENT_INCR('tableName')`.

I don't recommend relying on this, though.  If you pre-determine the next identity value this way, you're bound to end up in a situation where another process makes the insert that actually gets that ID before yours does, so your process ends up using the wrong ID value.

It's much better to make your insert first (even if you don't have all the data yet), and use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the actual ID assigned.

You might wonder why `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is better than `IDENT_CURRENT('tableName')`.  As the name implies, the former will give you that most recent identity value assigned within your current scope (your batch, your stored proc, whatever), whereas the latter will give you the most recent identity assigned on the table, by anyone.  Even though you might call `IDENT_CURRENT` right after '`INSERT`, it's still possible that someone else's `INSERT` occurs in between, and `IDENT_CURRENT` will give you the identity value that resulted from *their* insert instead of yours, whereas `SCOPE_IDENTITY` will always give you yours.

**EDIT**:

It's also worth mentioning that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is favored over the similarly-functioning `@@IDENTITY`.  While both return the latest identity value assigned within the current batch, `@@IDENTITY` is affected by inserts that occur within triggers; `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is not.

Comment: This was exactly the question and answer I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SELECT CAST(Scope_Identity() AS INT)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old...but you can get the inserted records ID by using an output parameter.

Here an example of a stored procedure I have

```
IF object_id('spOrganizationAdd') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE spOrganizationAdd;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spOrganizationAdd
    @OrganizationName VARCHAR(50),
    @ReturnIdentityValue INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TempOrganizationIdentity TABLE (TempOrganizationID INT)

    INSERT INTO Organization (OrganizationName)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.OrganizationID INTO @TempOrganizationIdentity
    VALUES (@OrganizationName)

    SELECT @ReturnIdentityValue = (SElECT TempOrganizationID FROM @TempOrganizationIdentity)
END
GO
```

Here an example of the C# code that calls it...note `ParameterDirection.Output`:

```
public static int AddOrganization(Organization oOrganization)
{
    int iRetVal = 0;

    using (SqlConnection conn = Connection.GetConnection())
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spOrganizationAdd", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrganizationName", oOrganization.OrganizationName);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnIdentityValue", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            iRetVal = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@ReturnIdentityValue"].Value);
        }
    }

    return iRetVal;
}
```

Class example

```
public class Organization
{
    public Organization() { }
    public Organization(int organizationID) { OrganizationID = organizationID; }

    public int OrganizationID { get; set; }
    public string OrganizationName { get; set; }

    public string Display()
    {
        return OrganizationID.ToString() + " " + OrganizationName;
    }
}
```